# IOS 8 homescreen web apps bug white space

Tags: web-applications, ios8, homescreen

There is a space of about 20px at the bottom of the screen.
I tried setting background color for body and other elements and the white space persists.
Anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style property like so:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

(it won't actually be black)

And you must recreate the home screen web app after you make the change; changing it the HTML document won't affect an already created web app.

Update: Actually, this is not a real solution. I just noticed that there is just a black space at the bottom of the page instead of white. So it's not as noticeable. You, like me, probably have a single page app layout with 100% (or 100vh) height. I'm not sure what the perfect solution is yet.